# Drupal » Print taxonomy terms

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, themes, taxonomy

I'm theming a node-MyContentType.tpl and I would like the ability to 'print' only a specific Vocabulary.

In other words, I would like something like that:

```
<Title>
<Vocabulary [1]>
<Body> 
<Vocabulary [2]>
```

I think it should be fairly easy, but I'm struggling....
Ideally, I would love to pass arguments to:

- print the "label" of the vocabulary (I'm currently doing it with a module )
- print the term as a link
- print the description of that term

Hope somebody can help me, thanks.

#### Update:

here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
foreach ( (array)$node->taxonomy as $term ) {
  // $term->name has the taxonomy term name
  // $term->tid has the taxonomy term id

$TermTitle = $term->name;
$TermDescription = $term->description;

print ($TermTitle);
print $TermDescription;
}
?>
```

Now, could somebody help me so that this only print a specific vocabulary, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Taxonomy Hide](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_hide) module gives you some fancy configurations with which to hide vocabularies and terms from display. Unless you have a complex use case that might change over time, you might want to hard-code it.

Take a look at `taxonomy_hide_nodeapi()` to get some ideas how you might adjust it to suit your needs. Interesting snippet:

`foreach ($node->taxonomy as $key => $value) {`
  `if (array_key_exists($value->vid, $hidden)) {`
    `unset($node->taxonomy[$key]);`

Answer (score 0):

another easy solution is you can use taxonomy treemenu module  [download here](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_treemenu), it will then  read QUICKSTART file from there to know how create tree  minue , go to block and you will find block for that menu , display it anywhere you need .
(renamed the block in correct name if there is error message ) 
.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Views for this.

Import this View to start

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'taxonomy_terms2';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'term_data';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'name' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_taxonomy' => 0,
    'exclude' => 1,
    'id' => 'name',
    'table' => 'term_data',
    'field' => 'name',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'phpcode' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'value' => '<?php
$term_link = \'taxonomy/term/\'.$data->tid;
if (arg(0)==\'node\') { // If we\'re on a node, get the node\'s term and compare it to this term
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
    if ($data->tid == $term->tid) {
            $extra_class = "active-term";
    }
  }  
} else if (arg(0)==\'topic\') { // If we\'re on a view, compare the first two arguments of the view\'s alias to the term\' alias
  if(drupal_lookup_path(\'alias\', $term_link) == arg(0) . \'/\' . arg(1)) {
    $extra_class = "active-term";
  }
}
print l($data->term_data_name, $term_link, array(\'attributes\' => array(\'class\' => $extra_class)));
?>',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'phpcode',
    'table' => 'customfield',
    'field' => 'phpcode',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'weight' => array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'id' => 'weight',
    'table' => 'term_data',
    'field' => 'weight',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'vid' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'vid',
    'table' => 'term_data',
    'field' => 'vid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('footer_format', '5');
$handler->override_option('footer_empty', 0);
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'list');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'grouping' => '',
  'type' => 'ul',
));
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'vid' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      '49' => '49',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'vid',
    'table' => 'term_data',
    'field' => 'vid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('block_description', '');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

Then just pick your vocabulary

Answer (score 0):

I used this to print the Taxonomy name where vocabulary id matched 1. It's hard coded, but it was good enough for my needs.

```
// Print the Product Type
// Print Taxonomy terms where vid == 1
foreach ($node->taxonomy as $key => $value) {
  if ( $node->taxonomy[$key] -> vid == 1) {
    print ( $node->taxonomy[$key] -> name );
  }
}
```